# Prevent HTML encoding in auto-generated GridView columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView bound to a DataTable that I construct.  Most columns in the table contain the raw HTML for a hypelinklink, and I would like that HTML to render as a link in the browser, but the GridView is automatically encoding the HTML, so it renders as markup.

How can I avoid this without explicitly adding HyperLink, or any other, columns?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<del>Simply set the [`BoundColumn.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx) property to false:</del>

<del>`<asp:BoundField DataField="HtmlLink" HtmlEncode="false" />`</del>

---

I am afraid that there is no easy way to disable HTML encoding of the contents in a `GridView` with [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)`= true`. However, I can think of two workarounds that might solve the problem you are facing:

**Option 1:** Inherit the `GridView` class, override the `Render` method, loop through all cells, decode their contents, before executing the base method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rows.Count; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++) 
    {
        string encoded = Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
        Rows[i].Cells[j].Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(encoded);
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** In a class inheriting from `GridView` or in the `Page` or `Control` using it, make your own inspection of the `DataTable` and create an explicit `BoundColumn` for each column:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
{
    GridViewColumn boundColumn = new BoundColumn
        {
            DataSource = column.ColumnName,
            HeaderText = column.ColumnName,
            HtmlEncode = false
        };
    gridView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
}
```

Comment: HtmlEncode="false" is not recommended due to potential XSS attacks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 10):

I was able to achieve this by using the solution that Jørn Schou-Rode provided, I modified a little bit to make it work from the RowDataBound Event of my Gridview.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
           for (int j = 0; j < e.Row.Cells.Count; j++) 
           {
               string encoded = e.Row.Cells[j].Text;
               e.Row.Cells[j].Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(encoded);
           }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to add something like the following to the RowDataBound event handler...

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        For Each col As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            Dim encoded As String = col.Text
            col.Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(encoded)
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Use OnRowCreated

```
    protected void gvFm_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            BoundField fldRef = (BoundField)((DataControlFieldCell)cell).ContainingField;
            switch (fldRef.DataField)
            {
                case "ColToHide":
                    fldRef.Visible = false;                        
                    break;
                case "ColWithoutEncode":
                    fldRef.HtmlEncode = false;                        
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well since the html for the link is in your db already, you could just output the html to a literal control.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="myLink" SortExpression="myLink">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litHyperLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("myLink", "{0}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This should render your link as raw text allowing the browser to render it as the link you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Since all the answers seem to be in C# and the questions was not specific, I ran into this issue using ASP.Net and VB.Net and the accepted solution did not work for me in VB (though I imagine it does work in C#). Hopefully this helps anyone working with VB.Net in ASP who stumbles upon this as I have.

In VB.Net `BoundColumn` cannot be added to `Gridview.Columns` as it is not a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField` so instead one must use a `BoundField` which is a `DataControlField`.

`BoundColoumn` also does not have an `HtmlEncode` property however `BoundField` does. Also, in VB.Net `DataSource` becomes `DataField`.

```
        For Each dataCol As DataColumn In dv.Table.Columns
            Dim boundCol As New BoundField With {
                .DataField = dataCol.ColumnName,
                .HeaderText = dataCol.ColumnName,
                .HtmlEncode = False
            }

            gvResult.Columns.Add(boundCol)
        Next

        gvResult.DataSource = dv
        gvResult.Databind()
```

Also note that you must explicitly set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` or the GridView will still generate columns along with the columns added above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in RowDataBound event if you want to disable HTML encoding in all rows and columns.

```
protected void GV_Product_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (TableCell ObjTC in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ObjTC.Text);
            ObjTC.Text = decodedText;
        }
    }
}
```