# How to bring the data from the database without the HTML tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, reporting-services, informix

I face the following problem.

I use text editor to allow the user to format the data before storing it in the DB.

My problem is when retrieving the data from my data base to show it in my report (report viewer ). the data appeared with the `HTML tags` in a very bad view !

How to fix this problem?

I tried this method :

```
Server.HtmlDecode()
```

but invain

Comment: reporting services version? 2008 provides placeholders. you can choose in the markup type that html tags will be interpreted as styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to remove all html tags using Regular Expressions as:

```
// I use this static method to make it faster.
private static Regex oClearHtmlScript = new Regex(@"<(.|\n)*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static string RemoveAllHTMLTags(string sHtml)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sHtml))
         return string.Empty;

    return oClearHtmlScript.Replace(sHtml, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: then i will lose the format as well?? , i hope there 's some way to keep the format without showing the tags .(rendering the text in the correct format)

Comment: I do't have the code in front of me now cause i leave the office . but as i remember it's a cell o f table

Comment: @just_name If you won to keep the html format, you need to disable the automatic html encode of your controls, or use other type of rendering the results, eg use Literal control. If you have the code of your rendering we can see some possible solutions.

Comment: @just_name Look and this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168649/prevent-html-encoding-in-auto-generated-gridview-columns

Answer (score 2):

quote: You tried this method Server.HtmlDecode()

From what you are stating its not coded in the first place for this to work. You can use Decoder utf8Decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder(); to work with it or convert to Unicode.

it will still show up in the reports but won't have the drastic impact you talk about.

The best option tho is to use a Regular Expression as stated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [html formatted textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562%28v=sql.105%29) to display the field. It's not clear from the question if it's desired behavior, but this would in fact render some html tags your users entered (such as `<b>`). It doesn't support all tags, but I'm not 100% sure what it does if it doesn't recognize a tag (it may just ignore/hide it).

Edit: as @varg reminded me with a comment to the question, availability depends on your SSRS version.