# Random introduction of HTML Tags in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, html

I hate asking for help on what I know has to be an easy fix, but for the life of me I can't figure out where my problem lays.

I have a SQL database on my ASP.net project and for some reason, I am now picking up HTML tags in my strings.

For example, this sentence:

"Additional Settings" is completely greyed out.

will turn into this:

@quot;Additional Settings@quot; is completely greyed out.

The sentences are typed in manually so it can't be there, the columns are saved as varchar(max) so I dont think it could be there. When I bring it into a gridview it looks fine. Its when I use:

```
 GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(5).Text
```

That I receive my strings with HTML tags.

Why is my gridview exporting strings with html tags when I didnt enter them with html tags and didnt save them with html tags?

Thanks guys for the help.

Comment: I think this might be the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168649/prevent-html-encoding-in-auto-generated-gridview-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah of course I figure out the answer on the very next web page I read dohhh >_<

```
 HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(DefectsGrid.Rows(lines).Cells(5).Text)
```

Sorry guys for wasting your time