# How to Replace CSV String in LINQ Query , Wanted to Replace CSV with NewLine in LINQ

Tags: string, linq

I have CSV field which is coming from SQL DB. But when shown in gridview i want to replace csv with New Line. I have tried on working out with below code. but still doesnt work on web apps.

```
    var query = (from r in objEntities.Student
                    select new
                    {
                        FullName = r.FullName.Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine)
                    }).ToList();

        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Looking forward!

Comment: What about it that "doesn't work"...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace with **`<br />`** : *A line break*

and also you may need to set `HtmlEncode="false"` property of the column  if it is `BoundField`

if the column is auto generated to set `HtmlEncode` as false check below post

[Prevent HTML encoding in auto-generated GridView columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168649/prevent-html-encoding-in-auto-generated-gridview-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Html does not recognize new lines as actual line breaks when rendered. Instead try this:

```
   var query = (from r in objEntities.Student
                select new
                {
                    FullName = r.FullName.Replace(",", "<br />")
                }).ToList();
```