# How to add a hyperlink to gridview manually

Tags: c#, asp.net

So here is the code and i have the following problem, i don't know how to create a hyperlink object for the column.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = null;   
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Име на настанот", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Информации за настанот", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Локација", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Време и датум на настанот", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Измени", typeof(HyperLink)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Бриши", typeof(string)));


foreach (Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry entry in calFeed.Entries)
{ 
    HyperLink a = new HyperLink();
    a.NavigateUrl = "aaa";
    dr = dt.NewRow(); 
    dr["Име на настанот"] = entry.Title.Text.ToString();
    dr["Информации за настанот"] = entry.Content.Content.ToString();
    dr["Локација"] = entry.Locations[0].ValueString.ToString();
    dr["Време и датум на настанот"] = "Почеток: " + entry.Times[0].StartTime.ToString() + " Крај: " + entry.Times[0].EndTime.ToString();
    dr["Измени"] = a.NavigateUrl; //what to add here how to add a hyperlink
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt; 
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

The error i get is:

> The XML element 'EnableTheming' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.

Answer (score 2):

Make that column a normal string:

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Измени", typeof(String)));
```

Then you can simple assign an HTML code for the link:

```
dr["Измени"] = "<a href='aaa'>Click Here</a>";
```

Comment: Well i have already tried that and it doesn't work. It is rendered as text.

Comment: Set HTMLEncode property for that GridView column to False: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx

Comment: Your *DataTable* columns are manually created. You mean GridView columns are autogenerated?

Comment: The GridView columns aren't autogenerated, how to access the autogenerated?

Comment: Are or aren't? If they aren't autogenerated - then simple set HTMLEncode property in in grid markup. If they are autogenerated - I suggest define columns in markup instead - much less pain for the situations like you're in now. If they are autogenerated and you cannot define them in ASPX - take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2168663/961695

Comment: They are not autogenerated, sry for commission.

Comment: I have tried with HTMLEncode and only a string, noting happens.

Comment: @MakiMalio then it's easy. Locate "Измени" column in your ASPX page in grid markup, and in that code set HtmlEncode to false, e.g. `<asp:boundfield datafield="Измени" htmlencode="false" headertext="Измени"/>`

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens?

Comment: Well i haven't solved the problem, maybe because i am manually creating the gridview.

Comment: The actual problem is when i create the column, i don't know what type of variable the put in, because the string is not working.

Comment: I think you're confusing DataTable creation with GridView creation

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the RowDataBound event. Or use the <asp:TemplateField> in your grid, this way you can add custom html into a column.