# How to encode html data in asp / vb.net boundcolumn datagrid?

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, datagrid, html-encode

I have some data in database which I am binding it to a bound column.
Data contains many html tags. 
But I want to display it as TEXT only "NOT TO RENDER IT"

I am not sure because HTMLENCODE property doesn't work with boundcolumn.
Please help.

Also just to add I have multiple datagrids binding with `bind()` function and are using one event handler Itemdatabound.

```
<asp:boundcolumn datafield="content" readonly="True" headertext="Product ID ">
<headerstyle horizontalalign="Center" width="100px"></headerstyle>
<itemstyle horizontalalign="Left" width="100px"></itemstyle>
</asp:boundcolumn>
```

Comment: what do you mean, doesn't work? I see where MS says it does work with boundfield? can you switch? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Then i have to make boundcolumn to boundfield ?
Does that make any confliction to the code behind >>??

Comment: I could not answer this without seeing codebehind. I would guess that some changes would be in order.

Comment: i cant do anything with the boundcolumn ???
any extra code with htmlencoding i can write in code behind >??

Comment: yes, that is correct.You can see David's solution, or mine, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

`Server.HtmlDecode()`

This will allow you to print the tags without rendering them to html.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: how to use it with boundcolumn  datagrid ??

Comment: please make answers? It helps others follow your solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Prevent HTML encoding in auto-generated GridView columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168649/prevent-html-encoding-in-auto-generated-gridview-columns)

extract from possible solution from above link:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="myLink" SortExpression="myLink">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litHyperLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("myLink", "{0}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Or bind your own columns, also shown in above link